# Why does a full-width flexbox column squash its siblings?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When trying to create a table-like layout where one main column should consume all available space, the main column ends up taking up more space than desired and pushes other columns outside the bounds of the container.

The behavior I'm seeking is as if I were using a table to lay this out and I gave a column `width: 100%`.

If you look at the example below, you'll see that the second column of the first row is squashed even though the overflow is to be hidden. The first column seems to have some kind of sizing priority over the others.

I'm curious why this happens and what a reusable solution is. I don't want to set a fixed-width on any of the columns.

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.list-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

.list-column {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.list-column--main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.hide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/master/vendor/autoprefixer.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
<style type="unprocessed" id="AutoprefixerIn">%css%</style>
<style id="AutoprefixerOut"></style>
<script>
AutoprefixerSettings = ""; //Specify here the browsers you want to target or leave empty
document.getElementById("AutoprefixerOut").innerHTML = autoprefixer(AutoprefixerSettings || null).process(document.getElementById("AutoprefixerIn").innerHTML).css;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-row">
      <div class="list-column list-column--main hide-overflow">
        The main column that has a very very very very very very very very very very very  very very very very very very very very very very long title
      </div>
      <div class="list-column">
        <a href="#">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-row">
      <div class="list-column list-column--main hide-overflow">
        A shorter title
      </div>
      <div class="list-column">
        <a href="#">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `flex-shrink` property, you can specify which columns should shrink more when something is too wide for the box.

```
.list-column {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
.list-column--main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 100;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

The `list-column--main` columns is the only column that grows, but it's also the only column that shrinks. The other column(s) will not grow past their original size and will not be allowed to shrink.

I had expected from reading the spec that `flex-shrink: 1` would work well enough, but in practice, something much larger like `flex-shrink: 100` actually did what I wanted.

Further reading (flexbox spec): http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-shrink

Comment: This works! I would like to know exactly why it works this way and why `flex-shink: 100` works but `flex-shink: 1` doesn't, if someone would elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

If I were to answer this question today in 2020, I'd recommend this:

```
.list-column {
  flex: none;
}
.list-column--main {
  flex: auto;
}
```

`flex: none` ensures the right column never changes from the original size it needs to contain
its contents.
`flex: auto` allows the main column to grow and shrink as space allows. Much simpler than
understanding and applying every property individually.

In my other answer, I incorrectly added `flex-basis: 100%`, which told the browser that this
element should take up the entire width of the row and is why it needed `flex-shrink: 100` to correctly apply the shrink.

Good overview of flex on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
Better explanation of how flex works here (but weak on explaining the shortcuts): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.list-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

.list-column {
  flex: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.list-column--main {
  flex: auto;
}

.hide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-row">
      <div class="list-column list-column--main hide-overflow">
        The main column that has a very very very very very very very very very very very  very very very very very very very very very very long title
      </div>
      <div class="list-column">
        <a href="#">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-row">
      <div class="list-column list-column--main hide-overflow">
        A shorter title
      </div>
      <div class="list-column">
        <a href="#">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```